# My inputs get mixed while working on a Search Engine!!!(How to properly include another cin into a While-Cin loop)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool endsWith(const std::string &mainStr, const std::string 
&toMatch)
{
if (mainStr.size() >= toMatch.size() &&
mainStr.compare(mainStr.size() - toMatch.size(), 
toMatch.size(), toMatch) == 0)
return true;
else
return false;
}

bool startsWith(const std::string& mainStr, const std::string& 
toMatch)
{
if (toMatch.length() <= mainStr.length()
&& std::equal(toMatch.begin(), toMatch.end(), 
mainStr.begin()))
return true;
else
return false;
}

int main()
{
std::string FullString, SourceInput, SearchString, 
FormattedSearchString, plus = "+", multiply = "*", dot = ".";
std::cout << "Enter search string: ";
std::cin >> SearchString;
std::cout << "Enter source string: ";
while (std::cin >> SourceInput && SourceInput.find("END") 
== std::string::npos) {
FullString += SourceInput + " ";
FormattedSearchString = SearchString.substr(0, 
SearchString.length() - 1);
signed int StrLoc = 
FullString.find(FormattedSearchString) + 1;
signed int Found = 
FullString.find(FormattedSearchString, StrLoc);
if (Found < 0)
    Found = FullString.find(FormattedSearchString, 
StrLoc - 1);
if (endsWith(SearchString, plus) == true) {
    if (startsWith(SourceInput, 
FormattedSearchString) == true || endsWith(SourceInput, 
FormattedSearchString) == true) {
        std::cout << "You found it at: " << Found 
<< " and the word is: " << SourceInput << std::endl;
    }
}
else if (endsWith(SearchString, multiply) == true) {
    if (SourceInput.find(FormattedSearchString) != 
std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "You found it at: " << Found 
<< " and the word is: " << SourceInput << std::endl;
    }
}
else if (endsWith(SearchString, dot) == true) {
    if (endsWith(SourceInput, 
FormattedSearchString) == true) {
        std::cout << "You found it at: " << Found 
<< " and the word is: " << SourceInput << std::endl;
    }
}
}

std::cin.ignore();
char letter;
std::cout << "Press any key to continue...";
std::cin.get(letter);
return 0;
}
```

Hello guys so I'm working on a simple search engine and I included the code above which works without any problems. Although when I try to include;

```
std::cout << "Enter search string: "
std::cin >> SearchString;
```

inside my while loop to prompt user to enter more than one search strings after the user inputs SourceInput, my inputs get messed up and I can't use my while loop anymore. Basically when I input my SourceInput one by one(with whitespaces),the program reads some of my inputs as a SearchString . Please, this project is due to tomorrow and I need help!
Here is a sample run of this project:

```
Enter source string: Cars are fast END
Enter search string: fast+
index: 9 word: fast
Enter search string: r*
index: 2 word: Cars
index: 6 word: are
Enter search string: s.
index: 3 word: Cars
Enter search string: r+
Enter search string: s*
index: 3 word: Cars
index: 11 word: fast
Enter search string: s.
index: 3 word: Cars
Enter search string: QUIT
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `std::cin >> SourceInput` reads up to the first whitespace. If you want to read a line of text including spaces, use `std::getline(std::cin, SourceInput)`

Comment: I know,although I want to read my SourceInput word by word not as a line

Comment: Well then, don't put `std::cin >> SearchString` in the middle of the loop in which you read `SourceInput` word by word. Or, read the whole line of source, the whole line of search, and *then* process them word by word (e.g. with the help of a `stringstream`)